# Error : messaging/registration-token-not-registered

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, apn

Would anyone be why i get this error when i try to send a notification to a Iphone Physical device ??

```
Error sending message { Error: Requested entity was not found.
    at FirebaseMessagingError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:42:28)
    at FirebaseMessagingError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:88:28)
at new FirebaseMessagingError (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:254:16)
    at Function.FirebaseMessagingError.fromServerError (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:287:16)
    at Object.createFirebaseError (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging-errors.js:34:47)
    at /srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging-api-request.js:76:42
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
  errorInfo: 
   { code: 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered',
     message: 'Requested entity was not found.' },
  codePrefix: 'messaging' }
```

It's saying that my registration token is not registered.
After looking into the firebase doc i saw that :
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#admin_sdk_error_reference

messaging/registration-token-not-registered :

The provided registration token is not registered. A previously valid registration token can be unregistered for a variety of reasons, including:

- The client app unregistered itself from FCM
- The client app was automatically unregistered.(This can happen if the user uninstalls the application or, on iOS, if the APNS Feedback Service reported the APNS token as invalid.)
- The registration token expired. (For example, Google might decide to refresh registration tokens or the APNS token may have expired for iOS devices.)
- The client app was updated, but the new version is not configured to receive messages.

For all these cases, remove this registration token and stop using it to send messages.

But i feel like i already filled all the requirement (APNS is already configured and added into Firebase console)
[image]
(Already create in Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles of my Apple developper account)
[image]

I even add the code that ask for user permission (It also works, when i test it on my device)

```
  getIOSPermission() {
    _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
        IosNotificationSettings(alert: true, badge: true, sound: true));
    _firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered.listen((settings) {
      print("Settings registered:$settings");
    });
  }

  void requestIOSPermissions() {
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            IOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.requestPermissions(
          alert: true,
          badge: true,
          sound: true,
        );
  }

if (Platform.isIOS) {
  getIOSPermission();
  requestIOSPermissions();
}
_firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token) {
  print("Firebase Messaging Token: $token\n");
  usersRef
      .document(firebaseUser.uid)
      .updateData({"androidNotificationToken": token});
});
```

I also followed all the steps specified in the FCM package readme about the IOS Integration.
https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging

**Here my AppDelegate.swift code :**

```
import UIKit
import Flutter

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
    }
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

Any idea why i still get this error  ?

**Fcm log:**
[image]
**PostMan log :**

[image]

**BTW it works fine for android**

Comment: Try to add this method in Appdelegate,     func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    FIRMessaging.messaging.APNSToken = deviceToken
}

Comment: @manishsharma93 This is not working, i'm using flutter ..

Comment: @JeremyDormevil have you find any solution?

Comment: I just had to follow all the step again but this time using a Mac

Comment: I am getting the same error and using mac. Any suggestions on what needs to be done?

Comment: I received this error too. I was using a custom `apiKey` in my (Flutter) app's FirebaseOptions (one that was limited to iOS apps), but even though this was a further unrestricted key (it could be used for any GCP API) apparently it did make a difference for FCM, causing the token registration to fail. So I reverted it to the general API key that you get when downloading the GoogleService-Info.plist and that at least yields a successful response from the `/send` API.